# readonly property of lightning:input not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, lightninginput, lightningselect

I am using `lightning:input` of different types. Using `readonly=true` in input of type text is working but does not work for `checkbox` or for `lightning:select`.

Anyone got any clue for this?

Comment: what browser are you viewing this on?

Comment: @SimonLawrence Google chrome

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use attribute `disabled` instead of `readonly`.

Here's an example with `lightning:input` [checkbox] and `lightning:select`:

```
<div>
    Checkboxes
    <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Red" name="red" checked="true" disabled="true"/>
    <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Blue" name="blue" disabled="true"/>
</div>

<br/>

<div>
    <lightning:select name="selectItem" label="Select an item" value="2" disabled="true">
        <option value="">choose one...</option>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
    </lightning:select>
</div>
```

[image]

---

HTML docs say that `readonly` does not work for **checkbox** and that **select** does not have a `readonly` attribute.

[Doc for select](http://www.faqs.org/docs/htmltut/forms/_SELECT_READONLY.html):

> SELECT ... does not have a READONLY attribute. The reason is that
>   technically  lists don't have values... they have selected
>   options, which themselves have values. You may wish to see , which disables the  list.

[Doc for checkbox](http://www.faqs.org/docs/htmltut/forms/_INPUT_DISABLED.html):

> It's important to understand that READONLY merely prevents the user
>   from changing the value of the field, not from interacting with the
>   field. For many types of fields, READONLY is irrelevent because you
>   don't normally change the value. In checkboxes, for example, you can
>   check them on or off (thus setting the CHECKED state) but you don't
>   change the value of the field. DISABLED, however, actually prevents
>   you from using the field. Notice in these examples that you can set
>   the checkboxes even though they are "read only"

Both suggest using the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: yes that can certainly be a workaround, but I don't want it to show disabled, rather I want to show them read only, and after click of an 'edit' button, want them all to be editable. Showing all fields disabled by default doesn't pose a good picture, but keeping them read only makes it look good.

Comment: HTML docs say that readonly does not work for checkbox and that select does not have a readonly attribute. I have updated my answer. Please have a look. Both docs suggest using the disabled attribute.

Comment: Thank you! I was using this with `<lightning-input  type="search"/>` and using disabled was exactly what I needed. Using `read-only` covers the search icon.

Answer (score 1):

The `readonly` attribute is not supported on input type="checkbox" - as you can see by fiddling around here:

https://jsfiddle.net/xue78fhd/

to stop a checkbox being fiddled you need to do add a little javascript event "hack" to the the onclick, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wfVFW/3/

Answer (score 1):

yes, readonly maynot work as intended for checkbox/toggle type lightning input, but we can handle this in js code.
if we want it to be fixed in checked/unchecked under certain conditions, we can make use of onchange attribute to fix value in checked/unchecked

in html of LWC

```
<lightning-input type="toggle" data-name="fixvalue" label="Toggle" onchange={toggleHandler} message-toggle-active="Yes" message-toggle-inactive="No" checked={isChecked}>
</lightning-input>
```

in js code:

```
    toggleHandler(){
        if(//your condition where you want checkbox/toggle input to be
        fixed)
        {
            //assume you want it to be checked always
            this.template.querySelector('lightning-input[data-name="fixvalue"]').checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            your regular toggle/checkbox handler
        } 
    }
```